# How can generate c# classes from xsd file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I want to convert one XSD file into c# class. So I have use this command on prompt command windows:

```
xsd myxsdFile.xsd / classes
```

I have below error message. How can I fixed it?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217665/how-to-generate-net-4-0-classes-from-xsd and MSDN entry https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s2x1sy7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Can you post an excerpt / example of your XSD?

Comment: Does your XML schema have references to toher XSD files using the '<import>' element? You might need to download /add these additional schema files as well and make sure that the paths reference it in the import elements...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using xsd.exe to generate c# files, getting error and warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491619/using-xsd-exe-to-generate-c-sharp-files-getting-error-and-warnings)